# Hibernate - set of compound values

Tags: java, hibernate

I need a `Collection` of compound values in Hibernate. Something like:

```
class Parent {
    Set<Child> children;
}

class Child {
    String property;
    String anotherProperty;
    MyOtherClass oneToOneClass;
}
```

The key requirement is that elements in this collection are value objects. When I `saveOrUpdate` the `Parent` it also saves its children.

More importantly when I create another `Parent` with `children` based on the same set, these children need to be persisted separately. That's why regular `one-to-many` does not work for me.

Is there a clean way I can do it with Hibernate? Something like collection of values described here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html - but for a concrete, compound class.

I prefer solution in XML rather than annotations.

Comment: Are these children always of the same type?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, both are concrete classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you map this as composite-element

```
<set ... >
  <key .../>
  <composite-element class="Child" ...>
    <property name="property"/>
    <property name="anotherProperty"/>
    <nested-composite-element name="oneToOneClass">
      <property name="..."/>
    </nested-composite-element>
</set>
```

See [Component Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html).